# SSL Broken Pipe with PHP

Tags: php

My error output looks like this:

> PHP Warning: fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe in /home/whitelot/public_html/webservies/mylastwishnew/apnstest.php on line 89

and then every subsequent write to that resource gets the error:

> PHP Warning: fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe in /home/whitelot/public_html/webservies/mylastwishnew/apnstest.php on line 89

It works for a while, for maybe a few hundred messages/payloads, then all of a sudden pipe breaks and water goes all over the floor.

Anyone have any ideas if there is a good fix for this problem?

Comment: Do you want to add the code for `apnstest.php` to the question?

Comment: This error also occurs when the production gateway is addressed with the development (sandbox) certificate.

Comment: I stumbled on this by inadvertently writing a huge string to query parameters:
`file_get_contents("https://www.example.com?a=" . str_repeat("a", 1000000));`

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the
    'keep_alive' => false
option for
    new SoapClient($url, $options);
solved the issue in my case. It seems like if you don't use keep_alive = false, the SOAP connection tries to re-use a previous connection, which gets rejected by SSL. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60329

Also, make sure this is not a question of max_execution_time or another limit that might prevent the SSL connection to finish successfully.